# php: img src minus two folders

Tags: php, url, parse-url

i have an url `<img src="http://gebhart.dk/gdk15/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/3023.jpg">`

but i need **"2015/02/3023.jpg"**

this is not working:  $value is the url

```
print_r(parse_url($value));

$tokens = explode('/', $value);
echo $tokens[sizeof($tokens)-3];
```

or

```
parse_url($value);
```

but then i get `<img src="/gdk15/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/3023.jpg">`

how can i get the url form the **img src** minus 2 folders?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and dirty:

```
$relurl=explode('/', $value);
$relurl=array_slice($relurl, -3);
echo implode('/', $relurl);
```